# What does while(*pointer) means in C?

Tags: c, loops, pointers

When I recently look at some passage about C pointers, I found something interesting. What it said is, a code like this:

```
char var[10];
char *pointer = &var;
while(*pointer!='\0'){
    //Something To loop
}
```

Can be turned into this:

```
//While Loop Part:
while(*pointer){
    //Something to Loop
}
```

So, my problem is, what does ***pointer** means?

Comment: `*pointer` "points" to the first character of string `var`; when the first character is 0 (numerically, not the character '0'), you exit from the loop

Comment: .... and hopefully that C book also explains why you shouldn't do this because it leads to exactly this kind of confusion ;)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
while(x) {
    do_something();
}
```

will run `do_something()` repeatedly as long as `x` is true. In C, "true" means "not zero".

`'\0'` is a null character. Numerically, it's zero (the bits that represents `'\0'` is the same as the number zero; just like a space is the number 0x20 = 32).

So you have `while(*pointer != '\0')`. While the pointed-to -memory is not a zero byte. Earlier, I said "true" means "non-zero", so the comparison `x != 0` (if `x` is `int`, `short`, etc.) or `x != '\0'` (if `x` is `char`) the same as just `x` inside an if, while, etc.

Should you use this shorter form? In my opinion, no. It makes it less clear to someone reading the code what the intention is. If you write the comparison explicitly, it makes it a lot more obvious what the intention of the loop is, even if they technically mean the same thing to the compiler.

So if you write `while(x)`, `x` should be a boolean or a C int that represents a boolean (a true-or-false concept) already. If you write `while(x != 0)`, then you care about `x` being a nonzero integer and are doing something numerical with `x`. If you write `while(x != '\0')`, then `x` is a `char` and you want to keep going until you find a null character (you're probably processing a C string).

Comment: The "not 0" answer is the right answer that the OP needs in this case, so +1.

Answer (score 3):

`*pointer` means dereference the value stored at the location pointed by `pointer`. When `pointer` points to a string and used in `while` loop like `while(*pointer)`, it is equivalent to `while(*pointer != '\0')`: loop util null terminator if found.

Answer (score 3):

Let's start with a simple example::

```
int a = 2 ;
int *b = &a ;
/* Run the loop till *b i.e., 2 != 0 
Now, you know that, the loop will run twice 
and then the condition will become false 
*/
while( *b != 0 )
{
 *b-- ;
}
```

Similarly, your code is working with `char*`, a string.

```
char var[10] ;
/* copy some string of max char count = 9, 
and append the end of string with a '\0' char.*/
char *pointer = &var ;
while( *pointer != '\0' )
{
 // do something
 // Increment the pointer 1 or some other valid value
}
```

So, the while loop will run till `*pointer` don't hit `'\0'`.

```
while( *pointer )
/* The above statement means the same as while( *pointer != '\0' ),
because, null char ('\0') = decimal value, numeric zero, 0*/
```

But the usage can change when you do, `while(*pointer != 'x'), where x can be any char`. In this case, your first code will exit after `*pointer hits the 'x' char` but your second snippet will run till `*pointer hits '\0' char`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can go for it.

Please note that `*pointer` is the value at the memory location the `pointer` point to(or hold the address of).

Your `*pointer` is now pointing to the individual characters of the character array `var`.

So, `while(*pointer)` is shorthand usage of the equivalent

```
while(*pointer!='\0').
```

Suppose, your string is initialized to 9 characters say "123456789" and situated at an address say `addr`(memory location).

Now because of the statement:

```
char *pointer=&var;
```

`pointer` will point to first element of string "1234567890".

When you write the `*pointer` it will retrieve the value stored at the memory location `addr` which is `1`.

Now, the statement:

```
while(*pointer)
```

will be equivalent to

```
while(49)
```

because ASCII Value of `1` is 49, and condition is evaluated to **true**.

This will continue till `\0` character is reached after incrementing `pointer` for nine times.

Now, the statement:

```
while(*pointer)
```

will be equivalent to

```
while(0)
```

because ASCII value of `\0` is `0`. Thus, condition is evaluated to **false** and loop stops.

**Summary**:

- In `while(condition)`, `condition` must be non-zero to continue loop execution. If `condition` evaluates to `zero` then loop stops executing.
- `while(*pointer)` will work till the value at memory location being pointed to is a `non-zero` ASCII value.
- Also you can use:

  ```
  if(*ptr){     //instead of if(*ptr!='\0')
    //do somthing
  }

  if(!*ptr){     //instead of if(*ptr=='\0')
    //do somthing
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

`*pointer` means exactly what it says: "Give me the value that's stored at the place that the pointer points to". Or "dereference `pointer`" for short. In your concrete example, dereferencing the pointer produces the one of the characters in a string.

`while(*pointer)` also means exactly what is says: "While the expression `*pointer` yields a true value, execute the body of the loop".

Since C considers all non-zero values as true, using `*pointer` in a condition is always equivalent to using the expression `*pointer != 0`. Consequently, many C programmers omit the `!= 0` part in order to practice boolean zen.