# How to dereference a void pointer inside strlen?

Tags: c, pointers, dereference

I wrote a signedness agnostic function to print `char` string in hexadecimal format.

```
void print_char2hex(void* cp) {

    const char *arr = (char *) cp;

    size_t i;

    for(i = 0; i < strlen( arr ); i++) {
        printf("%02X ", 0xFF & arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Why does the following code not compile?

```
void print_char2hex(const void *cp) {

    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < strlen( * (const char *) cp ); i++) {
        printf("%02X ", 0xFF & cp[i]);
    }
}
```

This is the error message:

```
passing argument 1 of strlen makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
```

Comment: You typecasted $cp$ as a $const char*$, then pass the dereferenced value to $strlen$. Basically you're trying to pass a $const char$ to $strlen$. Remove the dereference.

Comment: Additionally it is not possible to dereference a pointer to void (nor index)

Comment: @RandomPerfectHashFunction you meant to use backticks there...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Yeah I didn't see the $cp[i]$ below. That needs a typecast before indexing too. What do you mean by backticks?

Comment: Backtick is the ` character (also called grave accent); it delimits inline `code blocks`.

Comment: @JL2210 from the standpoint of someone getting acquainted with C, the issue with this code is that figuring out the proper syntax for `cpi[i]` when using `void*` for the first time, led me to tinker with the casting within `strlen` not realizing the casting would only affect that parameter passing vs. the entire function scope.
I'm still unclear as to the difference between `((const char *)cp)[i]` and `(const char *)(cp[i])`.

Comment: You don't need a cast in any of this. Default conversions (without casts) should do quite fine. The chance that you would detect and understand your errors would be much higher.

Comment: @JensGustedt I can do away with casting. I found that `printf("%02X ", (unsigned char) *cp)` is an even shorter solution.

Answer (score 6):

`strlen` expects a `char*`. You're passing a `char`. Change to: `strlen( (const char *) cp )` by removing the dereferencing.

There's also a problem in the `printf` statement. You need to cast `cp` there too. Change to: `printf("%02X ",0xFF & ((const char*)cp)[i]);`

Another remark is that it can affect performance to do the function call to `strlen` in the loop header. Maybe the optimizer can fix it, but to be sure it can be better to use an extra line for that.

```
size_t len = strlen( (const char *) cp );
for(i = 0; i < len ; i++) {
```

If you ask me, it also looks clearer.

Comment: In your last code sample, you mean `size_t len = strlen( (const char *) cp );`

Comment: Would it be possible to explain further `((const char*)cp)[i]` as it turns out I got `(const char *) cp` right away but I am missing some information as to why `(const char *)cp[i]` does not suffice.

Comment: @OneArb Because that would be equal to `(const char *)(cp[i])` which is something different.

Comment: What can I read to comprehend the difference as I know  "I don't know",but I don't know "what I don't know".

Comment: @OneArb It just comes down to operator precedence and associativity. It's not more strange than the fact that `x*y+z*w` is the same as `(x*y)+(z*w)`.

Comment: I  meant, what is the difference between `((const char *)cp)[i]` and `(const char *)(cp[i])`?

Answer (score 1):

> How to dereference a void pointer inside strlen?

Inside `strlen(const char *)`, a de-reference is not needed.  Simply pass `cp`.

```
void print_char2hex(const void *cp) {
  size_t len = strlen(cp);
  ...
```

Yet `strlen()` not needed.

```
void print_char2hex(const void *cp) {
  const unsigned char *p = cp;
  while (*p) {
    printf("%02X ", *p++);
  }
}
```

Comment: What about the point of using `*p != '\0'`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32153715/what-does-whilepointer-means-in-c

Comment: @OneArb `while (*p)` is functionally the same as `while (*p != '\0')`.  Code to your group's coding standard.  If none, code for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

`0xFF &` is unnecessary, the shorter solution is:

```
void print_char2hex(const void *cp) {
  const unsigned char *p = cp;
  while (*p != '\0') {
    printf("%02X ", (const unsigned char) *p++);
  }
}
```